# entab program which replaces 4 spaces with a tab

Tags: c, io, formatting

I wrote an entab program which needs to replace every \$n\$ spaces with 1 tab. I picked \$n\$ to be 4, so every 4 spaces should be 1 tab. I have a feeling that my code is far too complicated than it should be, and the logic I made it with could be much simpler.

The logic of the code:

Note: \$n\$ = 4

1. Get line from input and put it in line array.
2. Whenever n spaces is found in that line kick n-1 of them from the array and the remaining space is replaced with tab.
3. Print the line.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define MAXLINESIZE 100
#define TABSPACES 4

int mgetline(char *s, int lim);
void kick(char *x, char val);
int countx(char *x);
void swap(char* x, int i, int j);

int main(void) {
    char line[MAXLINESIZE];
    char *linep = line;
    char *tmp = 0;
    int tab = 0;
    int i = TABSPACES - 1;
    while (mgetline(line, MAXLINESIZE) > 0) {
        while (*linep) {
            if (*linep == ' ') {
                if (tab == TABSPACES - 1) {
                    while (i > 0) {         
                        tmp = linep - i;
                        kick(tmp, ' ');
                        linep--;
                        i--;
                    }
                    *linep = '\t';
                    tab = 0;
                }
                else
                    tab++;
            }
            else 
                tab = 0;
            linep++;
        }
        printf("%s", line);
        linep = line;
    }
    return 0;
}

int mgetline(char *s, int lim)
{
    int c;
    char *t = s;

    while (--lim > 0 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        *s++ = c;
    if (c == '\n')
        *s++ = c;

    *s = '\0';

    return s - t;
}

void kick(char *x, char val) {
    char *sp = x;
    int i = 1;
    while (*x) {
        if (*x == val) {
            while (countx(sp) - i != x - sp) {
                swap(sp, x - sp, countx(sp) - i);
                i++;
            }
            *(sp + countx(sp) - 1) = 0;
            return;
        }
        x++;
    }
}

int countx(char* x) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; x[i]; i++);
    return i;
}

void swap(char* x, int i, int j) {
    char tmp = x[i];
    x[i] = x[j];
    x[j] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The biggest thing you can do to improve your C style (and this also goes for any curly-brace language) is to **learn to love the `for` loop.**

```
foo(i);
while (bar(i)) {
    something;
    baz(i);
}
```

should *almost always* be recast as

```
for (foo(i); bar(i); baz(i)) {
    something;
}
```

Examples from your code:

```
char *linep = line;
while (...) {
    while (*linep) {
        // body
        linep++;
    }
    printf("%s", line);
    linep = line;
}
```

should be

```
while (...) {
    for (char *linep = line; *linep != '\0'; ++linep) {
        // body
    }
    printf("%s", line);
}
```

(Notice that I added an explicit comparison with `'\0'` for clarity — since it doesn't affect the generated code — and I changed your statement "`linep` increment" to the more readable "increment `linep`." [There's another reason to use preincrement over postincrement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c), but it doesn't matter until you get to C++.)

Here's another example:

```
void kick(char *x, char val) {
    char *sp = x;
    int i = 1;
    while (*x) {
        if (*x == val) {
            while (countx(sp) - i != x - sp) {
                swap(sp, x - sp, countx(sp) - i);
                i++;
            }
            *(sp + countx(sp) - 1) = 0;
            return;
        }
        x++;
    }
}
```

should be

```
void kick(char *sp, char val) {
    for (char *x = sp; *x != '\0'; ++x) {
        if (*x == val) {
            for (int i = 1; countx(sp) - i != x - sp; ++i) {
                swap(sp, x - sp, countx(sp) - i);
            }
            sp[countx(sp) - 1] = '\0';
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Let's keep working on the `kick` function. The next thing I notice is that you repeatedly call this function `countx(sp)` inside a tight loop. Surely that's a performance hit; it would make more sense to cache the value *once* in a local variable and then use the variable. But let's see what `countx(sp)` actually does.

```
int countx(char* x) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; x[i]; i++);
    return i;
}
```

Well, that's just `strlen(x)` (modulo some const-incorrectness). You should write

```
int countx(const char *x) {
    return strlen(x);
}
```

and then get rid of the `countx` function altogether. So now we have

```
void kick(char *sp, char val) {
    const int n = strlen(sp);
    for (char *x = sp; *x != '\0'; ++x) {
        if (*x == val) {
            for (int i = 1; n - i != x - sp; ++i) {
                swap(sp, x - sp, n - i);
            }
            sp[n - 1] = '\0';
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Next, I notice that `if (*x == val)`, we just do a bit more processing and then `return`. So we don't actually need that extra bit of processing to happen *inside* the loop; it makes more sense to say "loop until we find a `val`; then *break the loop*; then do more processing and return." Also, there's another convenient library function for the looping part of that: it's called `strchr`.

So the next most productive thing you can do for your programming skill is to **learn to love the standard library.**

```
void kick(char *sp, char val) {
    const int n = strlen(sp);
    char *x = strchr(sp, val);
    if (x != NULL) {
        for (int i = 1; n - i != x - sp; ++i) {
            swap(sp, x - sp, n - i);
        }
        sp[n - 1] = '\0';
    }
}
```

---

Okay, let's look at the remaining complexity in that `kick` function. What's this three-argument `swap` routine? I'm familiar with the idea of swapping *two* objects... does this rotate the three of them, or something?

...Ah, no, it's just doing some unnecessary array operations. Let's write it the normal two-argument way:

```
void swap(char *x, char *y) {
    char tmp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = tmp;
}

... swap(&sp[x - sp], &sp[n - i]); ...
```

Ah, wait, that call can be just

```
... swap(x, &sp[n - i]); ...
```

So now what do we have?

```
void kick(char *sp, char val) {
    const int n = strlen(sp);
    char *x = strchr(sp, val);
    if (x != NULL) {
        for (int i = 1; i < sp + n - x; ++i) {
            swap(x, sp[n - i]);
        }
        sp[n - 1] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Well, that's a lot of calls to `swap`. Let's see what's actually happening here... aha, I see, you're trying to bubble `*x` from the first position all the way to the end of the array. (But doing it in a very odd way where the value `*x` actually pops into the right place *immediately*, and then you spend the rest of the O(n) time just trying to get all the other elements back into their proper places.)

Okay, why do we want `*x` at the end of the array? (After all, we know its value is `val`, so we wouldn't even technically need to swap it.) ...Aw, really?

```
sp[n - 1] = '\0';
```

All that work, just to null it out? Okay, seems like we don't care about `*x`; all this loop is really trying to do is bump the *remaining* elements down by one position in the array. Again, **there's a library function for that.**

```
void kick(char *sp, char val) {
    const int n = strlen(sp);
    char *x = strchr(sp, val);
    if (x != NULL) {
        memmove(x, x+1, sp + n - x);
    }
}
```

Notice that since the `sp + n`th character of `sp` is `'\0'`, we can just `memmove` it with the rest of the characters; we don't need to treat it specially.

---

And now we can see that `n` is used in only one place, as a part of the expression `sp + n`; and now we know about `strchr`, so we can reuse it and move the expensive computation inside the `if` so that we won't waste time computing it if it's not going to be used.

```
void kick(char *sp, char val) {
    char *x = strchr(sp, val);
    if (x != NULL) {
        char *end = strchr(sp, '\0');
        memmove(x, x+1, end - x);
    }
}
```

---

Now we can go back up and look for the callers of `kick`. Turns out there's only one — `kick(tmp, ' ')` — so we don't need `val` to be a parameter; in fact we should inline the entire three-line body of `kick` straight into the one place it's called.

---

...And of course there's much more to clean up, but at this point I'll call it a day. I hope that by reading and studying answers like these, you'll learn how to apply the same kinds of thinking to your own code. A particularly good book on the subject is Kernighan and Plauger's *[The Elements of Programming Style](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070342075)*. (Don't worry that it deals in languages that may be unfamiliar to you. That's part of the point: the *techniques* of programming are largely language-independent.)

---

Oh, I suppose I should also point out some problems starting from the *top* and working down. First, look up `strstr`. Then, try your program on the input `"hello\tworld\nhello    world"` (that's four spaces after the second "hello") and observe the trouble with it.

I vaguely recall that a working entab/detab program is one of the programs developed in Kernighan and Plauger's *[Software Tools](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/020103669X)*, which I recommend not as highly as *The Elements of Programming Style* but it's still pretty good. I also have a working version [here](http://www.club.cc.cmu.edu/~ajo/free-software/detab.c).

Comment: Nice cleanup! I will wait one day more to see if there will be more improvements and compare with this. Then i will accept this as answer if it is the best one.

Comment: And you have a good point by using standard library's functions, but because i am beginner i want to learn much more by making my own functions.

Comment: @Siliproksi: "because i am beginner i want to learn much more by making my own functions" — I know what you mean, but please do consider that you cannot become a painter without *looking*, and you cannot becomes a writer without *reading*. Studying the Old Masters (e.g. `<string.h>`) is a much better way to learn to paint like an Old Master than just bumbling about with a paintbrush. You *might* stumble across the proper techniques on your own, but then again you might not!

Comment: Also, even if you do write your own functions, you *must* learn to name them properly. `countx` is simply the *wrong name* for the function you wrote (the right name being `strlen`). Again you could defend with "As a beginner, I don't want to just read the dictionary; I prefer to make up my own words"; but again that attitude won't advance your skills as far or as fast as the alternative.

Comment: I disagree with the statement *"it doesn't matter until you get to C++"*. C++ is not something you "graduate" to from C; it is an entirely different language. That said, I'm only quibbling with your phrasing, not your advice. In fact, I think pre-increment should be one's default choice, even in C, and post-increment should only be used if its unusual semantics are actually desired.

Answer (score 4):

#### Bug

You never reset `i` back to `TABSPACES - 1`, so only the first tab will be placed correctly.  The rest of the time, you will convert four spaces into three spaces plus a tab.

#### Inefficient moving of tail

Every time you replace four spaces with a tab, you have a loop that moves the tail of the string forward one step at a time, three times total.  First of all, you could speed that up 3x by moving the tail three steps in one pass, perhaps with one call to `memmove()`.  Second of all, you could avoid the move altogether if you just moved each character into place like this:

```
while (mgetline(line, MAXLINESIZE) > 0) {
    char *tail = linep;
    while (*linep) {
        *tail++ = *linep;
        if (*linep++ == ' ') {
            if (++tab == TABSPACES) {
                // Erase spaces already copied to tail.
                tail -= TABSPACES;
                // Replace with tab instead.
                *tail++ = '\t';
                tab = 0;
            }
        } else {
            tab = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("%s", line);
    linep = line;
}
```

With this solution you can get rid of your `kick()`, `countx()`, and `swap()` functions.

Comment: Notice that with this new algorithm, each character is "moved into place" only once, prior to being `printf`ed out; so you no longer need the `line` buffer at all — you can write the program as a Unix-style stream processor, entirely in terms of `getchar` and `putchar`, with about 2 local variables' worth of internal state. This will also allow you to entab very long lines, instead of being limited to ~100 columns.

Comment: There is much simpler solution for this (on my code). You wrote new code. It is not mine.

Comment: So i edited answer to solve it. Because posting broken code is not allowed. I did give you +1 for finding bug. If this was stackoverflow i would accept you answer, however, the point is to make code tidy not to find bugs. But it was my fault to have bugs.

Comment: @Siliproksi I think what you can learn from the bug I found is that you need to test your own code more.  In the future, I suggest constructing a test input designed to exercise your code thoroughly, and then comparing your program's output to the expected output of the test.

Comment: Actually i test my every program. For example i tested this program by giving its output to file and the see if the spaces became tab in ASCII code. But i guess i forgot to test this code.